# Propensity Score Matching with Covariates pre-treatment

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, econometrics, difference-in-difference, propensity-scores

I am applying a propensity score matching on R using the package [Matchit](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MatchIt/vignettes/MatchIt.html).
I read that to match the observations, you should take the covariates and balance them. However, only pre-treatment observations of such covariates must be selected for the matching, unless the covariates are not affected by the treatment.

**My problem**: If I filter the dataset only for the pre-treatment observations, I will get a final matched data with only the pre-treatment observations, which is not useful to me as I then need to run a regression with the full dataset of observations.

**Question:** How can I filter the dataset to get pre-treatment observations only, get the matching, and then use the matched dataset with FULL observations (pre- and post-treatment) to run the final regression?

Comment: On which statistical principle are you basing the choice of using matching and discarding data?  Why is a propensity score relevant here?  Consider using the full dataset and using multiple imputation for missing baseline measurements.  If more than 1/2 (depending on the absolute sample size) of the observations are missing your dataset may be unsuitable for answering the question at hand.

Answer (score 1):

In `MatchIt`, you tell the `matchit()` function which variables you want to match on. You don't need to filter the dataset before running `matchit()`. When you run `match.data()` on the `matchit` output, you will get a dataset that is a subset of your original data but only with the matched units. Follow the tutorials in the `MatchIt` [vignettes](https://kosukeimai.github.io/MatchIt/articles/MatchIt.html).

If, for whatever reason, your pre-treatment covariates and outcomes are stored in two different datasets, you can run `matchit()` on the dataset containing the pretreatment covariates and treatment, extract the matched dataset using `match.data()`, and then merge (i.e., left join) the outcome dataset with this matched dataset so that only those with rows in the matched dataset are retained.